# POST multipart/form-data with Objective-C for image and other parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I've looked into a good number of articles on how to do a multipart/form-data POST on iOS, but none really explain what to do if there were normal parameters as well as the file upload.

I have used the multipart/form-data POST on iOS & I had written the following code and it is uploading data but not image data

```
  - (void)postWithImage:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
```

{

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YourHostString"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString *boundary = @"----1010101010";

//  define content type and add Body Boundry
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictionary keyEnumerator];
NSString *key;
NSString *value;
NSString *content_disposition;

while ((key = (NSString *)[enumerator nextObject])) {

    if ([key isEqualToString:@"file"]) {

        value = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:key];

        NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:value], 1.0);
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\";\r\nfilename=\"screen.png\"\r\n\r\n",value] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:postData];
    } else {
        value = (NSString *)[dictionary objectForKey:key];

        content_disposition = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key];
        [body appendData:[content_disposition dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:value options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
        [body appendData:jsonData];
        //[body appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}

//Close the request body with Boundry
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Length"];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

}

Can anyone please help me to get why image data is not uploading

Answer (score 0):

I think you should append `@"content-Type"` before you append real data, like this:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n"
dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```